# Generate and parse Python code from C# application

Tags: c#, python, code-generation, ironpython, cocor

I need to generate Python code to be more specific [IronPyton](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2). I also need to be able to parse the code and to load it into [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). I just started looking at some tools. I played with ["Oslo"](https://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/Microsofts-Oslo-modeling-platform-the-M-language-and-NET) and made a decision that it's not the right tool for me. I just looked very briefly at [Coco/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/) and it looks promising.

Does anyone use Coco/R?
If you did what's your experience with the tool
Can you recommend some other tool?

Comment: What do you mean by "Oslo". The link is broken.

Comment: @IvanKochurkin "Oslo" used to be a Microsoft project. You can find more at https://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/Microsofts-Oslo-modeling-platform-the-M-language-and-NET.

Comment: So, please fix the link in your question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2) implementation itself includes [a parser](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/master/Src/IronPython/Compiler/Parser.cs) and [an AST representation](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/tree/master/Src/IronPython/Compiler/Ast) of Python programs which can be walked with a [`PythonWalker`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/master/Src/IronPython/Compiler/Ast/PythonWalker.Generated.cs).

Comment: That's a great information for me. +1 for now. Let me research it and if it does for me what I think does, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: This question was answered a long time ago, but I'd like to know: did you get anywhere with this approach?

Comment: Am I the only one that finds the IronPython documentation unreadable?

Answer (score 2):

Not really my area of expertise but you might want to try [ANTLR 4](https://www.antlr.org/). It has support for generating [Python 2](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python2) and [Python 3](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the [Dynamic Language Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview).  This will be a standard part of some later version of .Net and C# (.Net 4 from memory).

I've used it to compile and execute Python code generated at runtime, but I haven't played with all the AST stuff yet.

Comment: I did look at DLR that's why I want to generate IronPython code that is a DLR language.  Unfortunately, C# 4 doesn't going to have all the features of dynamic language.  So far you only can use dynamic keyword in C#4.  But in any case it's not my question.

Comment: You can do everything you want right now with IronPython and DLR.  I suggest you read the page I linked to in my answer as it talks specifically about generating an AST from Python code.  You do not need C# 4 to use the DLR.  If you are using IronPython 2.0 onwards, you are using the DLR!