# Python search for all strings in code

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to get a regex expression that i can plugin to find all strings in a file.  For example if i had a file that had

```
using System;

public class Test: TestClass{
    public int val1 = 0;
    public string val2 = "Value";
    //This is a "test" class
    public Test(value = "temp"){
        val2 = value;
    }
}
```

id want the expression to return ["Value", "temp"]

here is my python file im using now.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import codecs
import sys
import re
pattern = re.compile("((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)")
with codecs.open(filepath,"r","utf-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
       m = re.findall(pattern, line)
       for string in m:
           print string
```

Comment: Is this C#? Then, a more reliable approach would be to use the AST parser, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432998/generate-and-parse-python-code-from-c-sharp-application.

Comment: @SIslam `Value` and `temp` - the OP is looking for strings.

Answer (score 4):

Apply `re.findall` function on the lines which won't startswith `//`.

```
with codecs.open(filepath,"r","utf-8") as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip().startswith('//'):
            out.extend(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', line))
    print out
```

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty Do you need it to work for `/* */` comments as well?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's my point. If he wants it to work for all C#-like files, your solution won't always work.

Comment: @pushkin yes that would help as well,  but from my question originally the answer given works.